# Unit Testing array structure with correct type

Tags: php, unit-testing

Suppose i have an array base structure

```
$testData = [
    'key' => [
        'key2' => [
            'key3' => 'string',
            'key4' => 'int',
            'key5' => 'string',
            'key6' => 'float',
            'key7' => 'string',
            'key8' => 'int',
            'key9' => [
                'key10' => 'string',
                'key11' => 'string',
            ],
            'key12' => [
                'key13' => 'string',
            ],
        ]]];
```

I want to create a Unit Test to check if another array follows this structure with the respective types.

Is that doable?

Comment: Yes it is doable.

Comment: Some advice on how?

Comment: Recursive iteration would be my thought.